# How to locate the right path for a .js file when using require

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path, require

I have an ExpressJS project where I want to use .js module inside another. I use require to get the .js module but it can't find the module because the path is not correct. How can I see or find what is the correct path for a local module.

Here is my project hierarchy/structure
[image]

This is what I have tried inside programController.js - another thing is I don't quite understand using "." in path string.

```
var Program = require('.././program.js');
var FinishProgram = require('.././finishProgram');
```

Comment: In your example it would be `../../models/program`.  But when you start using paths like that it's not good.   What I tend to do is use my own application node_modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.` and `..` notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) in paths represent a path *relative* to the file they're being required from.

**Meaning of `.` and `..` Wildcards**

`.` - inside the same directory this file is in (also referred to as the current working directory)

`..` - inside the parent directory of the current directory

When you use multiples of these together it creates a relative path pattern. So for `programController.js` to access `program.js` your path should be

`var Program = require('../../models/program');`

This path means, go up 2 folders to the `App` directory and locate the `models` folder, then load the file `program.js`.

Following the same rules, you can also access `finishProgram.js`

`var FinishProgram = require('../../models/finishProgram');`

Comment: thanks for your answer @peteb, it works! But I can't figure out how this path string works. Inside app_server -> routes -> route.js I require all the controllers from app_server -> controllers -> .js - how should the require looks like?

Comment: Are you requiring all of them in a single `require` or are you doing 1 `require` per controller file you want to include?

Comment: 1 require per controller inside a route.js file

Comment: Your `require` would like something like this `var controller = require('../controllers/controller.js);` You only need one `..` because both controllers and routes are located in the same directory.

Comment: Alright now I see the pattern - thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

`.` represents the current directory and is redundant in your case.

The paths are simple relative paths that are used to determine how to navigate to the required files.

This should work for you:

```
var Program = require('../../models/program');
var FinishProgram = require('../../models/finishProgram');
```

Note that the extension `.js` is not required.